# does a service take up any of the app's resources?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-service

I have some things my app needs to do periodically
these things - if done while running the app itself, affect its performance - in terms, they make it VERY BAD

they have to do with downloading large jsons from the server and caching downloaded images

if i do all those things in a service, and the app is running while the service is running as well - will it affect any of the app's performance?

will the service take up any app memory allocated by dalvik ?

Comment: Use Traceview to learn where your "VERY BAD" problems stem from, rather than just guessing.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Service in a separate process, it will have less of an impact on the other parts of your app, but it will make communicating to the Service more difficult.

Are you saying that you *know* these operations affect performance? If so, what signs are you seeing? You may be running into problems because you're trying to run everything on the main thread; if so, using a background thread may solve the problem.

Comment: the performance affect is: 
1. listview scrolling strange
2. sometimes widgets stop reacting for a few seconds

right now i am using intentservice and asynctasks inside the intentservice
I want the service to run even if the app isnt running, but i want to know that when the app IS running, that it wont take up the same resources ?

Comment: There's no need to run an asynctask inside an IntentService. An AsyncTask runs an operation on a separate thread from within an Activity; an IntentService runs on operation on a separate thread in a Service.
If your Service is running, your app is running. Other *parts* of your app, such as its Activities, may be paused or even destroyed, but you're still using some resources for your app.